# PGF stacked bar graph not drawn correctly

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am having problem with the following code which is supposed to produce a simple stacked graph.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ybar stacked]
\addplot[fill=black]    coordinates {(0.00,0.10)};
\addplot[fill=black!66] coordinates {(0.00,0.20)};
\addplot[fill=black!33] coordinates {(0.00,0.30)};
\addplot[fill=white]    coordinates {(0.00,0.40)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}
```

Below is the output it generates which is not clearly well-aligned. If I explicitly specify `ymin = -0.1`, `ymax = 1.1`, the bar looks almost right, but it starts slightly below `(0,0)`. If I replace coordinates `(0.00,0.10)` with `(0.00,0.00)`, the bar looks just fine. I have absolutely no idea what the problem could be.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Adding `enlarge y limits=0.15` to the axis option is one possible solution.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8} 
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ybar stacked,enlarge y limits=0.15]
\addplot[fill=black]    coordinates {(0.00,0.10)};
\addplot[fill=black!66] coordinates {(0.00,0.20)};
\addplot[fill=black!33] coordinates {(0.00,0.30)};
\addplot[fill=white]    coordinates {(0.00,0.40)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

\end{document}

Comment: This looks different on my computer (the lowest segment starts below 0). What version of PGFPlots are you using? I'm using 1.10.

Comment: Gee, I forgot there is a minimal length to write in a comment. Keep giving me errors -- Mine is 1.8.

Comment: Mine is also 1.10, though it still doesn't work for me even with `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}`

Comment: @Ali -- thank you for your feedback. I tried and tried and tried again with xelatex and pdflatex, same output as I had shown. This is indeed generated by MiKTeK_Portable\tex\generic\pgfplots\pgfplots.revision.tex)
Package: pgfplots 2013/03/17 v1.8 Data Visualization (1.8-3-gaf58a29).